# How to join a list elements by ',' using streams with ' as prefix and suffix too

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have an insert statement like below

```
private final COLUMNS = "NAME,TYPE,STATUS,CATEGORY";

String values = list
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.joining(","));

String insertStatement = String.format("INSERT INTO ifc.documents (%s) VALUES (%s) ",COLUMNS,values);
```

I can easily put COLUMNS as no quotes required but for values, my SQL fails and complain about missing quotes for the code above.

So, I tried

```
 String values = list.stream()
.collect(Collectors.joining("','"));
```

But it fails with this one as well.So I did a workaround and added another statement prefixing and suffixing a single quote and it started working.

```
 values = "'"+values+"'";
```

To be more specific, if i have say "rest", "test" and "best" in list

then expected output is

```
'rest','test','best'
```

Anyone knows a better solution for this?

Comment: What are your inputs and your desired outputs? What errors are you getting?

Comment: Your problem is not really how to join with commas but how to quote the values. Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Rather than using streaming, why not just use plane old for loop to build the values?

Comment: `Collectors.joining("','", "'", "'")` does what you're asking.  But that's not a safe way to escape data for SQL!!

Comment: @Henry edited !

Comment: What is `list`?

Comment: `list` is `List<String> values` for abstraction suppose it's passed in as parameter to the method.

Comment: @gyan I am trying to be more functional rather than Procedural

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can actually use `Collectors.joining(CharSequence delimiter,CharSequence prefix,CharSequence suffix)` and you can look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-) for the API.

```
String values = list.stream().collect(Collectors.joining("','", "'", "'"));
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [overload of `Collectors.joining`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-) that takes prefix and suffix parameters.

```
 String values = list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.joining("','", "'", "'"));
```

This will place single-quotes around all your values correctly, assuming that all of your values are strings that need single quotes for the syntax.

But, as is the case with all problems involving constructing a query by concatenating values, it leaves your vulnerable to SQL injection.  A more secure and versatile solution involves using a [`PreparedStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html).  Value placeholders are `?` characters, and you can use various `setXyz` methods to set the values safely.  It protects against SQL injection and allows for any data types to be used, not just string types.

Comment: It's needed in End to End test framework only and I have to use native driver and hence I am fine with that but agree with SQLInjection point.

Answer (score 4):

Don't construct 'values' part using string concatenation as it opens a possibility for SQL Injection attacks.

I'd use a prepared statement here. You can still construct your request like this:

```
List<String> columns = Arrays.asList("column1", "column2", "column3");
String columnsFragment = columns.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(","));
String placeholdersFragment = columns.stream().filter(s -> "?").collect(Collectors.joining(","))
String insertStatement = String.format("INSERT INTO ifc.documents (%s) VALUES (%s) ", columnsFragment, placeholdersFragment);
```

And then use `insertStatement` with `PreparedStatement`:

```
PreparedStatement st = connection.prepareStatement(insertStatement);
for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) {
    // +1 because prepared statement parameters indices are 1-based
    st.setString(i + 1, values.get(i));
}
st.executeUpdate();
```

In this case the resulting query will look like

```
INSERT INTO ifc.documents (column1, column2, column3) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution use of [String.join](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-) method like to this

```
String result = "'"+String.join("','", list)+"'";

 Function<List<String>,String> function = list2->"'".concat(String.join("','",list2)).concat("'");
 System.out.println(function.apply(list));
```

or use [reduction](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/reduction.html) like to this

```
String result =   "'"+list.stream().reduce((s, p) -> s + "','" + p).get()+"'";
```

Comment: `String.join(delimiter, list)` is much more readable than the other alternatives presented in this question.